# Other orientations besides s and p polarization for reflection

Tags: optics, reflection, polarization

When talking about reflection of polarized light, one comes immediately back to Fresnel equations and Brewsters Angle. There, s and p polarization are defined as being perpendicular and parallel to the angle of incidence, respectively.

My question is: what about the other angles? It should be entirely possible to get a different orientation of the electric field vector that is neither parallel nor perpendicular. How are these cases covered?

Answer (score 2):

In almost all practical cases, the S and P polarization components of light are independent.  That means the S component will act as if it is alone, and the P component will act as if it is alone too.

Light that is polarized at an arbitrary angle, or light whose polarization is elliptical, can be decomposed (mathematically) into S and P components.  Similarly, arbitrary S and P components can be added together mathematically to yield light of a corresponding polarization angle/ellipticity.

So, to predict what happens when light of a particular polarization state is reflected from a surface, one can decompose the light into S and P components, calculate what each component does, then add the two reflected components coherently (taking phase shifts into account).  This will result in the reflected light having a new polarization state, depending on the relative phase shift and amplitude change between the two components.

Answer (score 1):

The reflectivity of a surface for a polarization between s- and p- goes as:

R(theta,phi) = Rs(phi)*cos(theta)^2 + Rp(phi)*sin(theta)^2

where:

Rs(phi) is the coefficient of reflection for s-polarized light

Rp(phi) is the coefficient of reflection for p-polarized light

phi is the angle between the Poynting vector and the surface normal (or angle of incidence)

theta is the angle between the electric field of light and the surface (or the unit vector of s-polarized light)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).